# config setup in integration test after migration to Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, integration-testing, hibernate-4.x

I have config class

```
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    private HibernateConfiguration() {}

    public Configuration configuration(Class clazz) {
        Configuration c = new Configuration();
        c.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, "org.postgresql.Driver");
        c.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/brush_and_pixel");
        c.setProperty(Environment.USER, "postgres");
        c.setProperty(Environment.PASS, "solaris");
        c.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        c.setProperty(Environment.AUTOCOMMIT, "true"); //"true");
            c.setProperty(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
            c.addClass(clazz);

        return c;
    }

    public static HibernateConfiguration getHibernateConfiguration() {
        return new HibernateConfiguration();
    }

}
```

I'm accessing it in test like so:

```
public void setUp() {
    /**/
    Configuration c = HibernateConfiguration.getHibernateConfiguration()
        .configuration(SettingsGroup.class).addClass(Setting.class);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory =  c.buildSessionFactory();

    settingsGroupDao = new SettingGroupDao();
    settingsGroupDao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

What is the recommended way to obtain the `sessionFactory` since `buildSessionFactory()` method is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

from [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-config):

**Example 2.4. Obtaining the org.hibernate.SessionFactory**

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application
    sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
            .buildSessionFactory();
}
```